# AWS Lambda - Could not determine an appropriate location for storing user secrets

Tags: aws-lambda, .net-6.0

We published our Net6 web API to an AWS Lambda but when we make a request it fails.

Status: 502 Bad Gateway

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

We get this on CloudWatch:

```
  2022-09-01T10:42:07.359-03:00 Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Could not determine an appropriate location for storing user secrets. Set the DOTNET_USER_SECRETS_FALLBACK_DIR environment variable to a folder where user secrets should be stored.
  2022-09-01T10:42:07.359-03:00 at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\repository\codetria\palier\backend\backend-palier\Src\Presentation\Palier.API\Program.cs:line 12
```

Program.cs - line 12:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

It's not the first time that we published an API in this way and we've never had to set this environment variable.

This's the command we use to publish the API

```
dotnet lambda deploy-function lambda-name `
  --region us-east-2 `
  --project-location $API_LOCATION `
  --profile profile `
  --function-runtime dotnet6
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just a similar error trying to deploy to AWS, for me it turned out to be that I a `UserSecretsId` in my csproj by mistake. The error went away when I remove this value. Here is a reference on how to use UserSecrets in deployed environments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was a [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/66219) in Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets that makes this happen. It was still in the package through version 6. Upgrading to a newer version of the package (like v8) should resolve the issue for you.